# Displaying GET request from HTTparty on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend, httparty

I currently have a simple ruby file named `example.rb`. How can I make a view that allows a user to submit information into a form and then have the information from the GET request returned to them? I understand how to use these requests from the console, but not from the front-end.

Resources on this topic would also be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class StackExchange
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.stackexchange.com'

  def initialize(service, page)
    @options = {query: {site: service}}
  end

  def questions
    self.class.get('/2.2/questions', @options)
  end

  def users
    self.class.get('/2.2/users', @options)
  end
end

stack_exchange = StackExchange.new('stackoverflow',1)
puts stack_exchange.users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the HTTParty gem is in your application's `Gemfile`.

Take `example.rb` and put it in `/app/models/stack_exchange.rb` — yes the file name does matter[0] (this isn't the purists place to put this, but for beginners it's fine and perfectly acceptable). Remove the code at the bottom you're using to test it as well.

in `routes.rb` add this route: `get '/test' => 'application#test'`

in your `application_controller.rb` add this method:

```
def test
  stack_client = StackExchange.new('stackoverflow', 1)
  @users = stack_client.users
end
```

in `app/views/application/test.html.erb` put the following:

`<% @users.each do |user| %><%=user.inspect%><br/><br/><% end %>`

Note: I would otherwise recommend adding views to `ApplicationController` but because I don't know anything about your application, I'll default to it.

hit http://localhost:3000/test and you should see the expected result.

[0] Rails does a lot "magic" under the scenes — it's really not magic but metaprogramming — where it tries to assume a lot of things about your application structure and naming conventions. If your class was named `Stackexchange` (note the lowercase `e`), `stackexchange.rb` would be automatically "mapped" to the class `Stackexchange`. More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: What is this general concept referred to as? Just so that I can have a general idea of what to Google for more info.